# Visual Studio c++ download and excecution for new computer with windows 8.1 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I just bought a new computer, with Windows 8.1 64bit installed and wanted to start developing in C++.I am new to Visual Studio, I used to do it with eclipse but suggestions I found in the internet were to prefer Visual Studio.

I tried to download Visual Studio C++ 2008 redistributable package (x64) from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336.
But I couldn't find where it was stored in my computer, after searching it with key words. Then I uninstalled it, to install again from scratch.

To uninstall it I opened my control panel and it saw that I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) installed already, assuming it comes with the computer I bought, and the date of installation matches this. I can't find though where it is stored so I can't open it.
When downloading Visual Studio 2008, it says I need to uninstall previous Visual Studio versions.

Bottom line:

1. Should I uninstall the Visual 2012 (x86) that probably came with the computer (which is 64bit)? Or should I use it (and try to find where is it located)?
2. If I shouldn't use the 2012: Was the 2008 version I tried to install good? (2008 gives an "old" intuition, but just my intuition).
3. Is there an easy way to find out where the application is located for excecution? Any specific file to look for?

thank you

Comment: @Niall The sentence `When downloading Visual Studio 2008, it says I need to uninstall previous Visual Studio versions.` is evident that they *already* have Visual Studio.

Comment: But that *isn't true*. VS2008 can coexist with earlier versions.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yes, *so can the redists*.

Comment: @Niall I agree that this aspect of the question is off as the redists can coexist also. I have Visual Studio 2008, 2013, and 2015 installed with no conflicts. I also have every redist installed and none of them have ever told me to uninstall the previous versions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VC++ `Redistributable` packages *only* include the ***libraries*** required to run applications built with the respective version of Visual Studio (for example `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable` is for Visual Studio 2012). 
**It does not include any version of Visual Studio.**

You *could* uninstall `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86)` but however as it was preinstalled on your computer, I imagine that some program pre-installed by the computer manufacturer requires it. ***It's probably not a good idea to remove that.***

1. So no, it's *not* a good idea to remove it.

In order to use the 2012 version of `Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable` you should install the `vs120` compiler, aka the VC++ compiler that comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

2. For developing with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, using `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable` is completely fine as it matches the compiler version. However if you want to use the newer 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 versions you need to use those respective versions of the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable`.

If you wish to use an up-to-date version of Visual Studio, try the [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2), or if you're feeling adventurous try the [Visual Studio 2015 Release Candidate](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs).

3. The application you built is *always* located in the project's directory, under `/Debug` or `/Release`, depending on whether you built a debug or release version of the application. If you do not know where your project folder is located you may right-click your project in the File pane and click `Open folder in Windows Explorer`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to download thee actual Visual Studio IDE from http://www.visualstudio.com/ . Try downloading the free [Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2) for a start.

The Visual Studio redistributable packages are actually the minimal runtime libraries to run C++ programs that were compiled with visual studio. You got a version installed by default even on fresh computers, otherwise you can't run many programs (they are also included with the IDE).

The redistributables are also often bundled with installers to make sure that others can run your programs.